# Validation rule fires - not sure why

Tags: validation, lead-conversion, partner

I have a validation rule on an accounts' field

```
AND (ISBLANK(Bill_To_Account__c),ISPICKVAL( Owner.UserType ,"PowerPartner"))
```

That checks for the 'Bill_To_account__c' to have a value, if the accounts' owner is a partner.

That works perfect.

I noticed a problem, that when a partner, wants to convert a lead to account, he gets that same validation rule firing

[image]

The weird thing, is that if a NON-partner user tries to do the conversion, it works!

The condition is met, but it does NOT fire if I am doing the conversion, while if my partner, who's the owner of the lead does the conversion - it DOES fire, weird.

- note, I have validation enabled for conversion

[image]

Any clue why the difference?

Comment: So you are saying that the condition is not met according to you but the validation still fires?. Can you post what the debug log says?

Comment: to clear: The condition IS MET - but does NOT fire if I do the conversion. pasting log...